# JSHint: Turn off missing semicolon warning

Tags: sublimetext3, jshint, sublimelinter

How do I turn off missing semicolon warnings with JSHint in Sublime? I have tried multiple things on the internet to no avail.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

*`asi`* is an option within the sublime linter that will suppress the semicolon warnings when set to true.

See [JSHint Info](http://jshint.com/docs/options/)

For additional information.

Ultimately, you'll want to create a `.jshintrc` file in your app root folder and add the following code inside:

```
{
   "asi": true,
}
```

Set the file type as `json`, save it and restart your ide.

Comment: Thanks @shennan!  Updated.

Comment: Add it where? I tried adding this in SublimeLinter settings, in SublimeLiner-settings-User and also in the "jshin" portion of the latter... all to no avail.

Answer (score 6):

By inserting the following line at the beginning of your .js Javascript file should work:

/*jshint -W033 */